# Mybatis-plus Oracle datasource jar showing 'loading with no message' on Linux - How to solve?

Tags: oracle, datasource, mybatis-plus

When I running this jar in linux,It's show loading and no message .
and all the time wait about 3 minute

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3FFh.png)

change my datasource and telnet the datasource ip ,but It's ok ,so I don't know how to deal with this question